# Reinstall Libre office 5.2.0

Tags: updates, uninstall, libreoffice

I had **LibreOffice** installed on Ubuntu 16.04. I used to use the breeze icons.

I noticed that there was an updated version and silly me I uninstalled and installed a beta version for 5.2.0 through tar.gz file.

Now it is not launching and I cannot remove it through the terminal and it says:

```
Depends: lodevbasis5.2-core (<= 5.2.0.0.beta1-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Cay anyone help me uninstall it completely and reinstall a version with breeze icons?

Comment: Please format title as a question! Otherwise it is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally by entering in the terminal the following command :

> `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*.*`

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer, since it was the solution to the problem! :) This helps others if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

To install from the download, you should have changed directory to the DEBS folder in the archive.

You then should have according to the readme you would have used

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

In this post https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/22466/how-to-uninstall-libreoffice-on-ubuntu-in-terminal/ they say you can use:

```
sudo dpkg -P libreoffice
```

I might try to change into the DEBS folder again, and use:

```
sudo dpkg -P *.deb
```

But I have not tried it.

According to this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dpkg.html

Uninstalling packages using dpkg, in most cases, is NOT recommended. It is better to use a package manager that handles dependencies to ensure that the system is in a consistent state. For example using dpkg -r zip will remove the zip package, but any packages that depend on it will still be installed and may no longer function correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove LibreOffice open a Terminal window and type:

> sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice
>   sudo apt-get update

To install the stable version of LibreOffice back:

> sudo apt-get install libreoffice

Official Ubuntu repositories always use stable branch of LO, not betas.

Comment: When I try to uninstall wtih purge this appears in my terminal   "  ds: lodevbasis5.2-core (<= 5.2.0.0.beta1-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution) "